# Spring 4 bean autowiring with generics

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired

I am using Spring 4 via Spring Boot 1.1.8 and have created a class to cache some data. The class relies on generics to work but I'm having trouble with Spring and autowiring this class as a bean in another service.

I get errors like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [orm.repository.BaseRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dataTypeRepository,propertyNameRepository
```

The class in question:

```
/**
 * The purpose of this class is to get data from a cache backed by a database 
 * and if it does not exist to create it and insert into the database.
 */
@Service
public class CacheByName<TRepo extends BaseRepository, TItem extends BaseWithName> {
    private final TRepo repo;
    private final Class<TItem> itemClass;
    private final Map<String, TItem> itemsCache; // TODO: change to better caching strategy

    @Autowired
    public CacheByName(TRepo repo, Class<TItem> itemClass) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.itemClass = itemClass;
        itemsCache = new HashMap();
    }

    public TItem getCreateItem(String name) {
        TItem item = null;
        if(itemsCache.containsKey(name)) {
            item = itemsCache.get(name);
        } else {
            // try and load from db
            item = (TItem) repo.findByName(name);
            if(item == null) {
                try {
                    item = itemClass.newInstance();
                    item.setName(name);
                    repo.saveAndFlush(item);
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    // TODO: log and handle better
                    return null;
                }

            }
            itemsCache.put(name, item);
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

The class BaseRepository extends JpaRepository as follows. Other actual repositories extend this one.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends Object, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    public T findByName(String name);
}
```

The class BaseWithName is a MappedSuperclass that defines a name property and getters/setters for it. Other more concrete entity classes extend this.

I am trying to inject the CacheByName class into another service like the following. Note that I am defining the actual repository and entity class as generics in the constructor:

```
@Service
public class DataImporter extends BaseImporter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyImporter.class);
    private final PropertyNameRepository propertyNameRepo;
    private final CacheByName<DataTypeRepository, DataType> dataTypeCache; 


    @Autowired
    public PropertyImporter(RestTemplate restTemplateD5,
                            CacheByName<DataTypeRepository, DataType> dataTypeCache) {
        super(restTemplateD5);
        this.dataTypeCache = dataTypeCache;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

My AppConfig.java looks like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateD5() {
        return RestTemplateFactory.createWithHttpBasicAuth(username, password);
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find much information about creating beans that use generics. I suspect I need to create another @Bean definition in my AppConfig but I wasn't able to implement anything that worked.

Comment: Why aren't you simply usings springs `@Cacheable` support instead? Just add an annotation and bingo, caching...

Comment: Yes thank you - I do plan to use that in the future but my question is more about bean instantiation rather than the caching aspect.

Answer (score 0):

As `BaseRepository` is also a generic type, I think you missed to add the generic type there. That should help Spring to find a proper bean to inject:

```
public class CacheByName<TRepo extends BaseRepository<TItem, ? extends Serializable>, TItem extends BaseWithName>
```

This should also make the cast no longer needed:

```
item = repo.findByName(name);
```